# MySQL where join NOT EXISTS or = 'default' or = ''

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join, not-exists

I am writing a MySQL query which gets a list of leads (leads from a submission form) and passenger count for that order where the lead detail is either missing or is empty or = `default`. So I have joined the lead_detail table but only know how to check if it does exist, not if it doesn't. This is what I have so far -

```
SELECT l1.id, (
    /* sub query to get the passenger count from field 22 */ 
    SELECT lm1.`value` FROM lead_detail lm1
    WHERE lm1.form_id = l1.form_id AND lm1.lead_id = l1.id
    AND lm1.field_number = 22
) passengers FROM lead l1

/* join our detail table */
LEFT JOIN lead_detail lm2 ON (l1.id = lm2.lead_id)
WHERE lm2.field_number = 29 AND lm2.form_id = 1
AND lm2.lead_id = l1.id AND (lm2.`value` = 'default' OR lm2.`value` = '')

/* make sure we are on lead form 1 and they have paid */
AND l1.form_id = 1 AND l1.payment_status = 'Paid'
```

Just as a reference, field number **22** = passenger count

Field number **29** = form access key (empty, `default`, or non existent)

It may be worth noting that this is Gravity Forms WordPress plugin but this is most definitely a custom action I am trying to achieve. lm2 table structure below -

```
(int) id
(int) lead_id
(int) form_id
(int) field_number
(string) value
```

Hopefully it is clear what I am trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the alias of the `lead_detail` sub-query, let's say `lm2`, or, the alias of the same table in the main query. Example:

```
/* sub query to get the passenger count from field 22 */ 
    SELECT lm2.`value` FROM lead_detail lm2
    WHERE lm2.form_id = l.form_id AND lm2.lead_id = l.id
    AND lm2.field_number = 22
```

Comment: Yeah fair point I have changed l to l1, the first sub query to from lm to lm1 and the join from lm to lm2. Thanks for your input

Comment: although I wouldn't really say this answers the question? I still have the same issue it was just a suggestion for improvement of code right?

Comment: Incorrect aliases in SQL queries can lead to unpredictable results

Comment: I can't agree more. Fixed it now but it still doesn't resolve my overall issue.

Comment: Can you explain a bit in detail what do you want to achieve, it is not clear...?

Comment: I need a conditional join so I can load records either where the second table is empty or the second table value = 'default'

Comment: Can your column `lm2.value` contain a NULL values by table definition ? It will be useful if you post your table structure.

Comment: the lm2 row either doesn't exist at all or contains a value such as 'default'. I will update the question with the structure.